# MySQL Connector, Streaming Resultsets and Batch Fetching

Tags: jdbc, mysql-connector, mysql

I was browsing through the MySQL Connector (5.1.24) source code and I noticed something unusual in the method `StatementImpl#createStreamingResultSet`

The javadoc says

> We only stream result sets when they are forward-only, read-only, and
> the fetch size has been set to **Integer.MIN_VALUE**
>
> @return true if this
> result set should be streamed **row at-a-time**, rather than read all at
> once.

This makes me believe that if we want to stream result sets in MySQL, then there is no option of retrieving rows in batches (say 100 at a time).

Is the assumption true that if the fetch-size is Integer.MIN_VALUE, then the results will be retrieved 1 row at a time? And wouldn't that be a performance hit?